# using split in a module node.js

Tags: node.js, npm, split, telegram-bot

```
var telegram = require('telegram-bot-api');
var api = new telegram({
token: '',
updates: {
    enabled: true,
    get_interval: 1000
}
});

api.on('message', function(message){
var chat_id = message.chat.id;

var str = message.text;
var word = str.split(" ");
var yr = word[1].split("/");
```

above is my code, use the telegram-bot-api. Problem is the "**split**", when the code run, there is error: "**TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined**". How can I use split in a module?

thank you

Comment: What do you get when you console this out: **message.text** ?

Comment: the problem is not with `split` as the error says, it seems your `message.text` is `undefined`...better check why `message.text` is `undefined`

Comment: @ElmerDantas
Oh no, my fault. Yes.. you are right XD thank very much

Comment: @FanLee you're welcome. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like either the variable str is undefined or alternatively the value `word[1]` is undefined. Split works fine in the node environment. I would test it out using some console.logs in the `api.on` callback. i.e `console.log('str>>>', str)` `console.log('word>>>', word[1])`